How to embed python scripts into LibreOffice Calc (v.24.8.3.2)
This is a repeat of How to embed python scripts into LibreOffice Calc because https://stackoverflow.com/a/70510410 does not work for me.
Specifically step 2:

With APSO installed, go to Tools -> Macros -> Organize python scripts.

Nothing happens when I click Organize python scripts

Version: 24.8.3.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community

APSO 1.4.2 installed (and showed a window) successfully for me on 24.8.3.2 for Windows. Try resetting the LibreOffice user profile (easiest way is to rename "/4/user" to e.g. "/4/user0" so you can restore it afterwards) and then installing APSO. Also, before APSO, we would embed scripts by unzipping the .ods file, and that's still a valid approach in case this doesn't work.

I re-installed LibreOffice, rebooted, re-installed the extension version 1.4.2 and rebooted.
It works now.
LibreOffice tries upgrading to version 1.4.2.3. Refuse the upgrade! The upgrade fails and causes the extension to not work. Keep version 1.4.2.
